# Infinite values error calculating weights using ipw

Tags: r

I am attempting to estimate a set of stabilized inverse probability weights for a propensity score model using the **ipw** package in R.  I have a dataframe with 34517 observations, of which, 155 are in my treatment group.

```
mfg_stabilized_full <- ipwpoint(exposure = pmd_dummy, family = "binomial", link = "logit",
                            numerator = ~1,
                            denominator = ~ mfgshare + owner_per + dist_km + network_density,
                            data = city_lehd_acs04)
```

When running, I get an error message saying there are NAs in the weights. When I attempt to calculate unstabilized weights by removing the numerator term from **ipwpoint()** the weights that are returned are infinite.

In both calls the underlying logistic models converge and return estimates for each of the covariates. Considering that the underlying logistic model completes, why would I continue to get infinite values for unstabilized weights and NAs for stabilized?

Comment: Are some of the probabilities zero?

Comment: When I ran a summary on the fitted values the min was above zero. Far as I know there are none.

Comment: Try using the `WeightIt` package. For simple cases like this, it does the same thing as `ipw` but has clearer syntax and errors.

Comment: I also had this problem and found out at that `ipw` cannot handle tibbles, tbl %>% as.data.frame solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

Check your exposure coding. A binary exposure should be coded as 0 and 1 as per the package manual. I ran into the same error when my exposure was coded as a factor.